# What is the purpose of 「順風満帆」 used in business context?

Tags: meaning, kanji, sentence

I was involved in a talk about certain company's future and a colleague wrote this in the middle of discussion:

> ここまで会社{かいしゃ}の経営{けいえい}が**あまりに順風満帆{じゅんぷうまんぱん}**　過ぎ{すぎ}でした。
>
> 本業{ほんぎょう}も、副業{ふくじょう}も果たして{はたして}、これからどうなってしまうのだろうと、正直心配{しょうじきしんぱい}でなりません。

I tried to translate what he had written and getting this meaning (edited as Chocolateさん suggested):

> Up to this point the company is running well. I'm really worried,
>   wondering 'what will ever become of both our main business &
>   side business' (in the future).

I'm in doubt for usage of the bolded part in first sentence, since literally "順風満帆" has "smooth sailing" meaning which usually maritime-related (if the term separated to 2 kanji groups, "順風" has "favored wind" meaning but "満帆" doesn't showed up anything relevant).

What I want to ask for:

1. What is the exact purpose behind usage of "あまりに順風満帆" term to tell about business condition of a company (i.e. running well)?
2. Are there another words, phrases or terms which similar or equally matched meaning with bolded structure in daily usage?

Comment: 「 **果たして**どうなってしまうのだろう(≂ **いったい**どうなってしまうのだろう)」と「心配**でならない** (≂ **とても**心配だ)」の英訳、間違ってませんか？

Comment: 「心配でならない」と「心配でなりません」で、何の変更もなくに? 自分では国語から英語までは翻訳の正確度が足らない。

Comment: ^ すみません、どういう意味かわかりません。Sorry, can't follow. Did you look up 「果たして+ an interrogative」 and 「～でならない」 in the dictionary? **果たして**どうなってしまうのだろう means "What will **ever** happen to~~"/"What will **ever** become of~~", and 心配**でならない** /心配**でなりません** means **とても**心配だ、**すごく**心配だ, "I am **really** worried".

Comment: @Chocolate すみません、気にするね。Perhaps I missed some bit of things. So, are you want to say "副業も果たして、これからどうなってしまうのだろうと、正直心配でなりません" as "The subsidiaries from this time will ever become 'worse', and I'm really worried" instead of proposed above?

Comment: 「本業も副業も、」Both the main and side businesses, 「果たしてこれからどうなってしまうのだろうと」What will ever become of, in the future 「正直心配でなりません。」to be honest, I am really worried. → "Honestly, I am really worried, wondering 'What will ever become of both my/our main business and side business in the future.'" って感じです

Comment: @Chocolate さあ、分かりました。質問が改訂しました。I edited the translation part as suggested without changing what I asked for.

Answer (score 2):

順風満帆 means, as you have found out, "smooth sailing". It holds the exact same meaning as in English, meaning "easy progress", so I'm not sure what you are confused about here.

> 1) What is the exact purpose behind usage of "あまりに順風満帆" term to tell about business condition of a company (i.e. running well)?

あまりに～すぎる is a phrase that means "too much" "excessively". So あまりに順風満帆すぎ means "too 順風満帆" = "too smooth" (in the sense that he was expecting it to be harder and therefore is worried something is wrong).

> 2) Are there another words, phrases or terms which similar or equally matched meaning with bolded structure in daily usage?

While you can take out the あまりに part since you have ～すぎる afterwards, leaving it in stresses the fact that things were very, very easy.

For words to replace 順風満帆, you could use one of the following:

> ・順調{じゅんちょう}: smooth, going w/o a hitch
>   ・予定通{よていどお}り: as planned
>   ・上手{うま}く行｛い｝く：things going well

And lastly, here is my take on the sentences you have, put together. This is heavily localized and not a word-for-word translation. Note what I did to the あまりに順風満帆すぎ part to help stress the point.

> So far, business has been smooth. Too smooth. I just can't help but be worried about what's going to become of both the main business and side business in the future.